# How to upload file to mongoDB from a route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

Sorry for such a basic question but I've really struggled to find a solution elsewhere online and I am trying to learn the MERN stack. I am trying to upload a file to mongodb and in my server.js file the following code uploads the file as expected. I can see the details of the file in the db. But when I try to move this into a route, so it is not in my server file, it fails. My main question is how can I take the following and add it to a `router.post('/fileupload'...)` as its own .js file in my routes folder so that it uploads to my db. Thanks!

```
var conn = mongoose.connection;
    if (conn !== "undefined") {
        var grid = require("gridfs-stream");
        var fs = require("fs");
        grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
        conn.once("open", () => {
            console.log("conn open");
            var gridfs = grid(conn.db);
            var streamwrite = gridfs.createWriteStream({
                filename: "tmp.txt"
            });
            fs.createReadStream("tmp2.txt").pipe(streamwrite);
            streamwrite.on("close", function (file) {
                console.log("Write written successfully in database");
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('sorry not connected');
    }
```

How I access the route from my server.js:

```
const fileupload = require("./routes/api/fileupload");
app.use("/api/fileupload", fileupload)
```

Comment: If the answer helped you then please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this -

**uploadRoute.js**

```
// Config
const config = require('../../../config/config');

// Logic
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require('fs');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

//models
const Files = require('../../../models/files.model');

module.exports = router => {
    const conn = mongoose.connection;
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    let gfs;

    conn.once("open", () => {
        gfs = Grid(conn.db);

        router.post('/bucket/upload', (req, res) => {
            let {
                file
            } = req.files;
            let writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
                filename: `${file.name}`,
                mode: 'w',
                content_type: file.mimetype
            });
            writeStream.on('close', function (uploadedFile) {
                Files.create({
                        doc_id: uploadedFile._id,
                        length: uploadedFile.length,
                        name: uploadedFile.filename,
                        type: uploadedFile.contentType
                    })
                    .then(file => res.json({
                        success: true,
                        message: "File was saved with success"
                    }))
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.error(`[*] Error, while uploading new files, with error: ${err}`);
                        res.status(500).json({
                            message: `[*] Error while uploading new files, with error: ${err}`
                        })
                    })
            });
            writeStream.write(file.data);
            writeStream.end();
        });
    });
}
```

For gridfs you need to provide a model in mongo to store data, you can give blank model or add some custom fields which will be part of mongo collection with some additional fields which gridfs adds.

**models.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    doc_id: {
        type: String
    },
    length : {
        type: Number
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    type: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('File', fileSchema);
```

Comment: This looks great! But what is the config line referring to? Do I put the logic pieces in the server file? What do I add to the models file?

Comment: Does all this go in the route file?

Comment: The config file is for our mongoose connection which I have removed. It is just a sinppet of how you can upload inside a route.