# Multer GridFsStorage Dynamic Configuration for Multiple MongoDB Connections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multer, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

So I'm using MongoDB Atlas, Mongoose, Multer and GridFsStorage to upload files to a single database on the cloud which works fine, but I want to be able to **upload files to different databases, using different database connections dynamically**.

In order to do this, **I want to set up my Multer GridFsStorage configuration so that the "db" property field changes dynamically based on the API request**. However, I can't access the HTTP request object inside the "db" property, which would make it possible for me to change the DB connection dynamically. The **"db" property** inside the GridFsStorage configuration object only accepts the following:
[image]

In the following example, you can see that I am creating a database connection using a custom getDatabaseConnection() method and then I pass that connection into the DB field that takes in a **single static DB connection**.

```
// Multer GridFsStorage configuration.
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    
    // I NEED TO CHANGE THE DB CONNECTION DYNAMICALLY TO UPLOAD FILES TO DIFFERENT 
    // DATABASES, BUT I HAVE NO ACCESS TO THE HTTP REQUEST OBJECT INSIDE THE DB FIELD!
    db: connectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection(process.env.DB_CONNECT), 
    
    // I can access the request object (req) inside the "file" field.
    file: (req, file) => {
        ...
    }
});
```

Is there **a way to access the HTTP request object inside the GridFsStorage configuration** so that I can set the "db" field dynamically with multiple DB connections, or am I approaching this the wrong way??

**UPDATE**: The owner of the multer-gridfs-storage project has commented on the issue on Github and it seems he's interested in adding it to its next release. You can [check out the issue on Github](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage/issues/457) to stay updated.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the functionality you are looking for is missing from the multer-gridfs-storage engine. You could try creating a new issue for a feature request on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage) of this node module.

I noticed that you are looking for a reputable source. It seems that [devconcept](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Edevconcept) is the primary contributor to this project. Hopefully he can help you out with this feature by suggesting a workaround, or by adding a function that accesses the HTTP request object in the db property and returns a Mongoose connection object to it (the function could be an alternative input option to the db property aside from the mongoose connection object).

### Edit

One other thing you could try is using the **createWriteStream()** function of the **gridfs-stream** package instead of using gridfs-store to upload your files. You can see an implementation of this function on the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639802/how-to-upload-file-to-mongodb-from-a-route).

Comment: I've already created an issue on the project's GitHub page but I haven't gotten an answer yet. Hopefully, @devconcept sees the issue soon... Although you didn't solve my problem you were the only person to post an answer to my question after all these days so I awarded you the bounty. Cheers

Comment: I made an edit to my answer to suggest an alternative solution to your problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: UPDATE: DevConcept has commented on the issue on Github and it seems he's interested in adding it :D